# Draw Box around Funnel Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have these two plots

plot1

[image: Plot1]

plot2

[image: Plot2]

As you can see plot 2 has a box around it and plot 1 doesnt. (the box within the graph)
Is there any way to draw a box around the 1st Plot?

This is the code

```
jpeg("Funnel.jpg", width = 3600, height = 2400, units = "px", pointsize = 40)
funnel(model, comb.fixed = T, comb.random=F, col.grid ="lightgrey", level = .95)
box(lty = '1511', col = 'black')
dev.off()

jpeg("Funnel-contours.jpg", width = 3600, height = 2400, units = "px", pointsize = 40)
funnel(model, comb.fixed = T, comb.random=F, contour=c(.9,.95,.99), col.contour=c("#CFCFCF","#DFDFDF","#EFEFEF"))
legend(-1, 1.25, legend = c("p < 0.10", "p < 0.05", "p < 0.01"), fill = c("#CFCFCF","#DFDFDF","#EFEFEF"), bty="n")
dev.off()



#

# print to svg file: width x height are in Inch
#


svg("Figure3.svg", width = 12, height = 12, pointsize = 30)
funnel(model, comb.fixed = T, comb.random=F, frame.plot=T)
dev.off()

svg("Figure4.svg", width = 14, height = 14, pointsize = 30)
funnel(model, comb.fixed = T, comb.random=F, contour=c(.9,.95,.99), col.contour=c("#CFCFCF","#DFDFDF","#EFEFEF"))
legend(-1, 1.25, legend = c("p < 0.10", "p < 0.05", "p < 0.01"), fill = c("#CFCFCF","#DFDFDF","#EFEFEF"), bty="n")
dev.off()
```

If you need any additional information dont hesitate to ask!
Thank you

Comment: Use can use `box("figure", lwd=8, lty = '1511', col = 'black')`

Comment: Thank you! This worked